# Remote access to Area Forecast Discussion

Tags: weather

Is it possible to access Area Forecast Discussion via SMS?  I fly to remote areas frequently (Wilderness), and after several days, it is almost impossible to get a good weather forecast, (one you're willing to bet your life on).  I wish I could get the Area Forecast Discussion via SMS over my inReach.

Comment: Thanks for the advice re. XM Wx.  I have used that, but I would like a longer forecast horizon - like a week. Here's what I've learned - you can download an FTP file of the Area Forecast Discussion, but the NWS system just responds to the email address that originated the query.  InReach doesn't allow replies to the initiating email address - even though it came from your device.  If they did, this would work.  I sent them an email last week but haven't heard back.

Comment: I have done something similar, and it might be possible to do it for the FA discussion. Essentially, I had a Google Sheet that would pull a table of data from a website, and in conjunction with IFTTT it would send a text message to a pre-defined number with the contents of that data table.  Since the avwx.gov page has a specific URL for each area discussion, this same concept would probably work.  Every 6 hours, the FA is updated, and you can time it so that the new discussion is texted to you at that interval.

Comment: But I'm confused: you said that you were looking for a product that had a longer forecast horizon of about a week... the FAs are only good for about an 18hr period.  ??

Answer (score 1):

I have an old Garmin 496 & XM which works great for this. XM lets you suspend your subscription in winter if you want to. Tom M

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into something like [XM WX Data](http://www.xmwxweather.com/xmwx-data/) which has pretty good remote satellite coverage for getting weather data when and where you need it. You may also want to consider installing an HF radio in your plane to potentially communicate with other ground stations in your area. Sometimes it boils down to [getting in the air and calling other stations as discussed here.](http://omegataupodcast.net/291-flying-in-the-papuan-bush/)